# proxy server is refusing connections on windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, firefox, proxy

I have a weird issue.I have a remote proxy server,with installed squid3.When access to proxy from Linux the server works perfectly,but from windows i get always the same message :

> the proxy server is refusing connections

Linux and windows have same IP and same version of Firefox who give me that message.
On windows I have check firewall settings and it seems OK.

thank you.

Comment: Make sure the port that you have set is correct. Squid should be listening on 3128 by default. Is that how the Windows version is set ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the firewall on your proxy server to make sure it's allowing connections from the Windows host as well as the Linux host?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused may be due to `add-ons` related with proxy or software like `spybot` please `disable` or `uninstall`  them. if still problem persists then `reset` your firefox.
I hope this will fix the problem.